# Large initial value on a UML class diagram from a java file?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

So from what I have seen, you can have an attribute and then set it to e.g. 10 initially and show that on the UML. However, this seems quite a different case to me...

```
private myTableModel someModel = new myTableModel("modelone") {
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            //some code here

        }
};
```

So what exactly would I do in this circumstance if this is my initial value of a class attribute? Seems ridiculous but at the sometime lawful to put it there. What are the thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

the initial value is not only large, but it is an expression so depending on the used target language (Java here) so yes do not put that in the model as the initial value

if you really want you can indicate it in the description of the attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the initial value like this

[image]

However, as you can see the tool (in this case EA) just truncates the inital value and will not display anything more. You could adorn you design with a SD showing the initialization sequence or more simply by adding a note to the class.

[image]